# How to dismiss a modal view controller, then immediately have the presenting view controller present a different modal view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm using an `IIViewDeckController` as my root view controller. It's a library that allows me to have a sliding menu view controller similar to the sliding menu in the facebook application. It works by initiating it with a center and left view controller and then setting the entire thing as the root view controller. Here's what that looks like in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
FeedViewController* mainFeed = [[FeedViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* mainStack = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainFeed];

MenuViewController* sideMenu = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];

IIViewDeckController* viewDeck = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:mainStack leftViewController:sideMenu];

self.window.rootViewController = viewDeck;
```

When in the center view controller (`navStack`), I have a button, that when pressed, presents a modal view controller, `login`:

```
- (void)openLogin{
    LoginViewController* login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

In `login`, after the user enters their credentials and logs in, I try to have the `navStack` dismiss `login`, and then immediately push in a different controller `creator`:

```
- (void)dismissLoginController{
    //get a reference to the mainFeed
    IIViewDeckController* viewDeck = (IIViewDeckController*)self.presentingViewController;
    UINavigationController* navStack = (UINavigationController*)viewDeck.centerController;
    FeedViewController* mainFeed = (FeedViewController*)navStack.topViewController;

    //have it dismiss login, then push creator
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [mainFeed openListingCreator];
}
```

`openListingCreator` in `mainFeed`:

```
- (void)openListingCreator{
    ListingCreatorViewController* creator = [[ListingCreatorViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* creationStack = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:creator];
    [self presentViewController:creationStack animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The error i'm getting is: `Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0xa40c790> on <IIViewDeckController: 0xa843000> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

I'm assuming this is because IIViewDeckController isn't on the screen when I ask it to present a view controller. However `openListingCreator` is being called AFTER i dismiss the `login` view controller, so I'm not sure why it's doing this. I believe it has something to do with IIViewDeckController since I have done this same exact process before in other projects without it and had no problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get this error because the `openListingCreator` is being called while the transition effect of the `LoginViewController` is still active. You could put the `[mainFeed openListingCreator];` in the completion block of `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` or present `creationStack` directly from the `LoginViewController`.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [mainFeed openListingCreator];
}];
```